# Jquery empty function does not remove video stream in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Here is the function I use to empty the div tag and start a new video stream. It works perfect in Firefox, Chrome, Safary, and Opera, but not in IE. In IE the video stream is not removed and the next one starts playing over the previous one. I think all other html elements are removed, but not the actual video.

```
function playChannel(id){
    $("#player").empty();
    request = $.getJSON("search.cfc",{
        method: 'playchannel',
        id: id,
        returnformat: 'json'
        },function(data){
        showPlayer(data);
        viewCount(id);
    });
}
```

Comment: It might help to post the `showPlayer()` code too.

Comment: I have the same problem with just a plain div and when I do `$("#player").html("new content")` it just adds that to the already existing content?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#player").html("");
```